# ActiveWorkbook.SaveAS filename:= using special characters

Tags: vba, excel

Admittedly I'm bad at knowing the lingo, so while I *think* I researched this thoroughly, there may be the perfect answer somewhere. Here's my dilemma, I'm developing this Excel VBA macro to backup and restore the Worksheet (basically giving me infinite Undos to the point I specify and short-cutting around saving and reopening):

```
Public BULast As String

Sub Backup()

'This macro imitates videogame save-states. It will save a backup that can replace to current workbook later if you've made an irreversible mistake.

'Step 1: Agree to run away if things go wrong (establish an error handler)
On Error GoTo BackupError

'Step 2: Create some variables
    Dim OriginalFile As String
    Dim BUDir As String
    Dim BUXAr() As String
    Dim BUExt As String
    Dim BUNam As String
    Dim BackupFile As String

'Step 3: Define those variables
    OriginalFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    BUDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    BUXAr = Split(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ".")
    BUExt = BUXAr(UBound(BUXAr))
    BUNam = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, "." & BUExt, "") & " (Back-Up)"
    BackupFile = BUDir & "\" & BUNam & "." & BUExt

'Step 4: Hide the truth
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Step 5(A): If there is no backup file, create one using the same file name as the one you're working with and throw a " (Back-up)" on it.
    If Dir(BackupFile) = "" Then

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=BackupFile

        ActiveWorkbook.Close

        Workbooks.Open filename:=OriginalFile

        BUYoN = vbNo

        BULast = Date & ", " & Time

        MsgBox "A Backup has been created!"

    Else

        BUYoN = MsgBox("This will restore the " & BULast & " backup and undo all changes made to this project. Continue?" _
            , vbYesNo, "Revert to Backup?")

    End If

'Step 5(B): If a backup has been created, restore it over the current workbook and delete the backup.
    If BUYoN = vbYes Then

        ActiveWorkbook.Close

        Workbooks.Open filename:=BackupFile

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=OriginalFile

        Kill (BackupFile)

        BUCheck = "Dead"

    End If

'Step 6: Put things back to the way you found them, you're done!
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Exit Sub

'Step 1 (Continued): If nothing went wrong, stop worrying about it, if something did, say it didn't work and go away.

On Error GoTo 0

BackupError:

    MsgBox "Attempt to Backup or Restore was unsuccessful"

End Sub
```

Normally it works as expected, but just yesterday it started not working and after playing around with it I realized it's because I was trying it on a file that has an Ω symbol in the file name.

The basic process is to look in the current directory for the active workbook's file name, but with (Back-up) tacked at the end. It will either create one, or replace the open one with what it finds. When done on an Ω file however, it substitutes that character with an O. When ran again, it apparently *searches* the the Ω correctly because it can't find any (even with the O-substitute file right there in plain sight).

I know the easiest solution would be to just make sure people keep their file names to what you can see on a keyboard, but that doesn't work for me; I'm almost religious about putting the adaptability in the *code* rather than the user. So with that long-winded back story, here's my specific question:

**Is there a SaveAs function or practical workaround in VBA that can handle special characters within the specified file name?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know we're not supposed to offer opinions, but it is my opinion that Rachel is a genius! I didn't know about the FileSystemObject, but that ended up being the key. Not only was it able to search for and recognized the file with special characters, but it appears it can delete it too. Incorporating that into the code makes it run flawlessly with or without special characters:

```
Public BULast As String

Sub Backup()

'This macro imitates videogame save-states. It will save a backup that can replace the
'current workbook later if you've made an irreversible mistake.

'Step 1: Agree to run away if things go wrong (establish an error handler)
    On Error GoTo BackupError

'Step 2: Create some variables
    Dim OriginalFile As String
    Dim BUDir As String
    Dim BUXAr() As String
    Dim BUExt As String
    Dim BUNam As String
    Dim BackupFile As String
    Dim BUfs As Object

'Step 3: Define those variables
    OriginalFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    BUDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    BUXAr = Split(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ".")
    BUExt = BUXAr(UBound(BUXAr))
    BUNam = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, "." & BUExt, "") & " (Back-Up)"
    BackupFile = BUDir & "\" & BUNam & "." & BUExt
    Set BUfs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


'Step 4: Hide the truth
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Step 5(A): If there is no backup file, create one using the same file name as the one
'you're working with and throw a " (Back-up)" on it.

    With BUfs
        If Not .FileExists(BackupFile) Then

            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=BackupFile

            ActiveWorkbook.Close

            Workbooks.Open filename:=OriginalFile

            BUYoN = vbNo

            BULast = Date & ", " & Time

            MsgBox "A Backup has been created!"

        Else

            BUYoN = MsgBox("This will restore the " & BULast & " backup and undo all changes made to this project. Continue?" _
                , vbYesNo, "Revert to Backup?")

        End If
    End With

'Step 5(B): If a backup has been created, restore it over the current workbook and
'delete the backup.
    If BUYoN = vbYes Then

        ActiveWorkbook.Close

        Workbooks.Open filename:=BackupFile

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=OriginalFile

        BUfs.DeleteFile BackupFile, True

    End If

'Step 6: Put things back to the way you found them, you're done!
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Exit Sub


'Step 1 (Continued): If nothing went wrong, stop worrying about it, if something did,
'say it didn't work and go away.

On Error GoTo 0

BackupError:

    MsgBox "Attempt to Backup or Restore was unsuccessful"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the Dir() function as it converts the special characters to ANSI before checking for the file and thus fails for these cases. Use the FileSystemObject object instead:

```
Sub Backup()

On Error GoTo BackupError

    Dim OriginalFile As String
    OriginalFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    ' get back up file name
    Dim BackupFile As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    pos = InStrRev(OriginalFile, ".")
    BackupFile = Mid$(OriginalFile, 1, pos - 1) & " (Back-Up)." & Mid$(OriginalFile, pos + 1)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Step 5(A): If there is no backup file, create one using the same file name as the one you're working with and throw a " (Back-up)" on it.
    Dim BUYoN As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim BULast As String
    Dim fs As Object
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    With fs
        If Not .FileExists(BackupFile) Then

            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=BackupFile
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=OriginalFile
            BUYoN = vbNo
            BULast = Date & ", " & Time
            MsgBox "A Backup has been created!"

        Else
            BUYoN = MsgBox("This will restore the " & BULast & " backup and undo all changes made to this project. Continue?" _
                , vbYesNo, "Revert to Backup?")

        End If
    End With


'Step 5(B): If a backup has been created, restore it over the current workbook and delete the backup.
    If BUYoN = vbYes Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=BackupFile
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=OriginalFile
        'Kill (BackupFile)
        fs.Delete BackupFile
        Dim BUCheck As String
        BUCheck = "Dead"

    End If

'Step 6: Put things back to the way you found them, you're done!
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Exit Sub


On Error GoTo 0

BackupError:
    MsgBox "Attempt to Backup or Restore was unsuccessful"
End Sub
```

Comment: Note: I re-wrote the section that builds the new file name because I thought that might be a source of the problem, however I am less certain of that now.

Comment: Hi Rachel, and thanks for taking the time to work on this! I put your code to the test using a file named "Bαckup Tεster Ω.xlsm". Your code is able to confirm that the file exists, which is a step further than mine. It bugs up at the Kill command, and the debugger shows the variable as "Backup Tester O.xlsm". Is there an alternative to Kill to delete a file?

Comment: I updated the code to use the `fs.Delete` command instead of the `Kill` command. `Kill` probably had the same issues as `Dir`, so this should work for you.

Comment: Thanks Rachel! This will be great! Also I really like your way of building the new file name; it's so simple and efficient! If I weren't such a new member I'd up-arrow you.